# Dynamics CRM error: The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

When trying to log into the CRM my users are seeing this error

[image]

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information for us to diagnose this. CRM Online or On Premise? What version? Where did you get the error message in the question title?

Comment: @jasonscript that error message came from the event viewer on the server.

Comment: I have actually figured it out. There was an issue with the trust relationship. ADFS had gotten out of sync with the claims-based authentication on the crm server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Launch the ADFS Console > Trust Relationships > Relying Party Trusts
2. Right click on the trust and select “Update from Federation Metadata…” (This needs to be done for all trusts)
3. Open Command Prompt at an elevated level type “iisreset”
4. Open “Services” and restart the “ADFS” service

If ADFS does not start, be sure to check the “Windows Internal Database” service and make sure it is started, and then try restarting the ADFS service

If the issue persists, continue with the following steps below:

5. Launch the “CRM Deployment Manager”
6. Run “Configure Claims-Based Authentication” wizard (Click “Next” all the way through the wizard)
7. Run “Configure Internet Facing Deployment” wizard (Click “Next” all the way through the wizard)
8. Perform steps 1-4 again

Comment: For us usually steps 5 to 7 do the trick, with an additional iisreset.